# Reposition file name from button to entry and use file names as global variables

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Currently:

Before execution (fig. 1)

[image]

after execution (fig. 2)

[image]

I am poor at tcl/tk. But nowadays I am studying tcl/tk for my work. I want to make GUI like figures. figure 1 is before clicking buttons. If I click right-side button and select files, the file names appear in the button text. I want to position these names in the middle-side entry region and want to use these file names as global variables. Here is my code. Could anyone help me?

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace eval ::dyna::partupdate {

    variable p_mainWin ".partupdate";

    variable str_curDir [file dirname [info script]];
    variable str_basefile "";
    variable str_appendfile "";
    variable str_spotweldfile "";
    variable str_outputfile "";
}

set types {
        {"LS-DYNA Files"     {.key .k .dyn .d } }
        {"IGES Files"     {.iges .igs } }
        {"MCF Files"     {.mcf } }
        {"All files"            *}
}

##############################################################################
##### Procedure Name: ::dyna::partupdate::CreateGUI
##### Functionality: creates the main window for file selection
##############################################################################
proc ::dyna::partupdate::CreateGUI {} {
    variable p_mainWin;

    destroy $p_mainWin;
    set base [ toplevel $p_mainWin];
    wm title $base {Update FE Model};
    wm resizable $base 1 1;

    set frm_main [frame $base.frm_main];
    pack $frm_main -side top -anchor nw -padx 0 -pady 0;

    set frm_fileselect [frame $frm_main.frm_fileselect -bd 0 -relief groove];
    set frm_create [frame $frm_main.frm_create -bd 0 -relief groove]
#    pack $frm_create -side right -anchor ne -padx 0 -pady 4;

    grid $frm_fileselect -row 0 -padx 1 -pady 4 -sticky nw;
    grid $frm_create     -row 3 -padx 1 -pady 4 -sticky ne; 

#    set frm_create [frame $frm_main.frm_create -bd 0 -relief groove]
#    pack $frm_create -side right -anchor ne -padx 0 -pady 4;

    # UI for base file
    set lbl_basefile [label $frm_fileselect.lbl_basefileName -text "Base File"];
    set ent_basefile [entry $frm_fileselect.ent_basefileName -width 30 \
                       -textvariable "::dyna::partupdate::str_basefile" -state disabled];
    set btn_basefile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_basefile -text " ... " \
                       -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.btn_basefile" ]

    grid $lbl_basefile -row 0 -col 0 -padx 5 -pady 7 -sticky nw;
    grid $ent_basefile -row 0 -col 1 -padx 5 -pady 7 -sticky nw;
    grid $btn_basefile -row 0 -col 2 -padx 0 -pady 6 -sticky nw;

    # UI for appended file
    set lbl_appendfile [label $frm_fileselect.lbl_appendfileName -text "Appended File"];
    set ent_appendfile [entry $frm_fileselect.ent_appendfileName -width 30 \
                       -textvariable "::dyna::partupdate::str_appendfile" -state disabled];
    set btn_appendfile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_appendfile -text " ... " \
                       -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.btn_appendfile" ]

    grid $lbl_appendfile -row 1 -col 0 -padx 5 -pady 2 -sticky nw;
    grid $ent_appendfile -row 1 -col 1 -padx 5 -pady 2 -sticky nw;
    grid $btn_appendfile -row 1 -col 2 -padx 0 -pady 6 -sticky nw;

    # UI for spotweld file
    set lbl_spotweldfile [label $frm_fileselect.lbl_spotweldfileName -text "Spotweld File"];
    set ent_spotweldfile [entry $frm_fileselect.ent_spotweldfileName -width 30 \
                       -textvariable "::dyna::partupdate::str_spotweldfile" -state disabled];
    set btn_spotweldfile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_spotweldfile -text " ... " \
                       -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.btn_spotweldfile" ]

    grid $lbl_spotweldfile -row 2 -col 0 -padx 5 -pady 2 -sticky nw;
    grid $ent_spotweldfile -row 2 -col 1 -padx 5 -pady 2 -sticky nw;
    grid $btn_spotweldfile -row 2 -col 2 -padx 0 -pady 6 -sticky nw;

    # UI for output file
    set lbl_outputfile [label $frm_fileselect.lbl_outputfileName -text "Output File"];
    set ent_outputfile [entry $frm_fileselect.ent_outputfileName -width 30 \
                       -textvariable "::dyna::partupdate::str_outputfile" -state disabled];
    set btn_outputfile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_outputfile -text " ... " \
                       -command "::dyna::partupdate::saveAs $frm_fileselect.btn_outputfile" ]

    grid $lbl_outputfile -row 3 -col 0 -padx 5 -pady 2 -sticky nw;
    grid $ent_outputfile -row 3 -col 1 -padx 5 -pady 2 -sticky nw;
    grid $btn_outputfile -row 3 -col 2 -padx 0 -pady 6 -sticky nw;

    set btn_update [hwt::CanvasButton $frm_create.btn_update \
    [::hwt::DluWidth 40] [::hwt::DluHeight 14] \
    -command "::dyna::partupdate::uPDATE" \
    -text "Update" ]

    set btn_close [hwt::CanvasButton $frm_create.btn_close \
    [::hwt::DluWidth 40] [::hwt::DluHeight 14] \
    -command "::dyna::partupdate::CloseWindow" \
    -text "Close" ]

    pack $btn_update -anchor ne -padx 5 -pady 5 -side left;
    pack $btn_close -anchor ne -padx 5 -pady 5 -side left;
}

proc ::dyna::partupdate::onSelect { label } {
    global types   
    set file [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $types -parent .]
    $label configure -text $file
}

proc ::dyna::partupdate::saveAs { label } {
    global types   
    set file [tk_getSaveFile -filetypes $types -parent . -initialdir .]
    $label configure -text $file
}

proc ::dyna::partupdate::uPDATE { args } {
    variable str_basefile;
    variable str_appendfile;
    variable str_spotweldfile;
    variable str_outputfile;

    set executable C:\CENSor\\CENSor.exe

    # base file name should not be empty
    if {$str_basefile == ""} {
        tk_messageBox -message "Please select an base file." -title "aaa" \
            -type ok -icon info;
        return;
    }

    # append file name should not be empty
    if {$str_appendfile == ""} {
        tk_messageBox -message "Please select an appended file." -title "aaa" \
            -type ok -icon info;
        return;
    }

    # execution case 
    if {$str_spotweldfile == ""} {
          exec $executable -e 0 $str_outputfile $str_basefile $str_appendfile
    }
    else {
          exec $executable -e 0 $str_outputfile $str_basefile $str_appendfile $str_spotweldfile
    }
}

proc ::dyna::partupdate::CloseWindow { args } {
    variable p_mainWin;

    set windowPath [lindex $args 0];
    if {[winfo exists $p_mainWin]} {
        destroy $p_mainWin
    }
}

# ----- bring up the main gui --------
::dyna::partupdate::CreateGUI;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, this line:

```
set btn_basefile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_basefile -text " ... " \
                   -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.btn_basefile" ]
```

will execute this proc:

```
proc ::dyna::partupdate::onSelect { label } {
    global types   
    set file [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $types -parent .]
    $label configure -text $file
}
```

The first line above will update the widget `$frm_fileselect.btn_basefile` which is the button, when `onSelect` is executed. You will first need to change the first line to modify the entry box, like so:

```
set btn_basefile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_basefile -text " ... " \
                   -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.ent_basefile" ]
```

Then change the proc so that it is able to edit the entry text (entries don't have a `-text` option, you have to insert. Usually it's better to delete everything just in case)

```
proc ::dyna::partupdate::onSelect { label } {
    global types   
    set file [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $types -parent .]
    $label configure -state normal   ;# makes the entry normal to allow editing
    $label delete 0 end              ;# delete everything
    $label insert end $file          ;# insert the text
    $label configure -state disabled ;# disable the entry again
}
```

Then you will have to modify the remaining 3 buttons similarly:

```
set btn_appendfile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_appendfile -text " ... " \
                   -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.ent_appendfile" ]

set btn_spotweldfile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_spotweldfile -text " ... " \
                   -command "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect $frm_fileselect.ent_spotweldfile" ]

set btn_outputfile [button $frm_fileselect.btn_outputfile -text " ... " \
                   -command "::dyna::partupdate::saveAs $frm_fileselect.ent_outputfile" ]
```

[manual for entry widget](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm)

---

As for the last part, you don't really need them to be global. You can use `widget get`, for example:

```
set filename [.partupdate.frm_main.frm_fileselect.ent_basefile get]
```

Will give you the text in the `Base File` entry (of course, if you have the widget path in a variable, it'll be easier)

```
set filename [.partupdate.frm_main.frm_fileselect.ent_spotweldfile get]
```

Will give you the one for `Spotweld File`, and so on.

---

<sup>Sidenote: I would probably rename the variable in `onSelect` from `label` to `entry`.</sup>

Comment: Jerry,  thank you for your kind answer. I modified code according to your advice. But, "onSelect" region, application error message appeared like follows. and file name was not appeared in entry region, also. could you give me help one more time?

Comment: invalid command name "configure"
  while executing
"configure $label -state normal   "
  (procedure "::dyna::partupdate::onSelect" line 4)
  invoked from within
"::dyna::partupdate::onSelect .partupdate.frm_main.frm_fileselect.ent_basefile"
    invoked from within
".partupdate.frm_main.frm_fileselect.btn_basefile invoke"
  ("uplevel" body line 1)
  invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list $w invoke]"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonUp" line 24)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonUp .partupdate.frm_main.frm_fileselect.btn_basefile"
 (command bound to event)

Comment: @Cha ahh oops my bad, I copied it wrong. It should be `$label configure` and not `configure $label`. I'll edit it.

Comment: How can I give you gold badge?

Comment: @Cha lol you cannot give a gold badge but you can click on the tickmark outline next to my answer to mark it as the solution, the tickmark will become green.